# Draw letters python

Tags: python, ascii-art

I have a homework and I have to do this:

The purpose of this program is to draw a set of rectangles (with sides parallel to the axes) using characters.

You will receive a sequence of rectangles, one per line, defined by the coordinates (X and Y) of your upper left and lower right corners.

You should "paint" all the rectangles using the # character. The X and Y coordinates grow right and down, respectively.

Input example:

```
0 0 2 8

0 7 8 8

10 0 12 8

10 0 18 1

10 7 18 8

20 0 22 8

20 0 28 1

20 7 28 8
```

Output example:

```
    ###       ######### #########
    ###       ######### #########
    ###       ###       ###      
    ###       ###       ###      
    ###       ###       ###      
    ###       ###       ###      
    ###       ###       ###      
    ######### ######### #########
    ######### ######### #########
```

I already made this:

```
import sys

def make_rectangules(first_coordenates, second_coordenates):

    for y in range(second_coordenates[1]-first_coordenates[1]+1):
        for x in range(second_coordenates[0]-first_coordenates[0]+1):    
            print('#')


def main():
    aux_list = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip('\n').split()
        line = list(map(int,line))
        first_coordenates = (line[0],line[1])
        second_coordenates = (line[2],line[3])
        make_rectangules(first_coordenates, second_coordenates)

main()
```

But I don't get the same result.

Comment: Have you already write some code?

Comment: Please don't beg for effort-free homework solutions.

Comment: I already edit my question with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it:

```
import sys

def main():
    aux_list = [[0, 0, 2, 8],
                [0, 7, 8, 8], 
                [10, 0, 12, 8],
                [10, 0, 18, 1],
                [10, 7, 18, 8],
                [20, 0, 22, 8],
                [20, 0, 28, 1],
                [20, 7, 28, 8]
               ]

    max_x = 0
    max_y = 0
    for elem in aux_list:
        if elem[2] > max_x:
            max_x = elem[2]
        if elem[3] > max_y:
            max_y = elem[3]

    array = [[" " for x in range(max_y+1)] for y in range(max_x+1)]
    for elem in aux_list:
        for i in range(elem[0], elem[2]+1):
            for j in range(elem[1], elem[3]+1):
                array[i][j] = "#"

    for x in range(max_y+1):
        for y in range(max_x+1):
            print(array[y][x], end='')
        print("")
main()
```

Result :

```
    >>python draw.py
###       ######### #########
###       ######### #########
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
######### ######### #########
######### ######### #########
```

This isn't the cleanest way to do it, but it works and this code sample can help you. Please take your time to understand this code, and ask me questions if you need some clarifications.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked fine! I will analyze and say you something soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
input_data = '''0 0 2 8
0 7 8 8
10 0 12 8
10 0 18 1
10 7 18 8
20 0 22 8
20 0 28 1
20 7 28 8'''

rectangles = [line.split(' ') for line in input_data.splitlines()]
output_list = []

for rect in rectangles:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = [int(coord) for coord in rect]
    for i in range(y1, y2 + 1):
        prev = output_list[i] if i < len(output_list) else ''
        if len(prev) < x2:
            prev += ' ' * (x2 - len(prev) + 1)
        prev = prev[:x1] + '#' * (x2 - x1 + 1) + prev[x2 + 1:]
        if i < len(output_list):
            output_list[i] = prev
        else:
            output_list.append(prev)

output = '\n'.join(output_list)
print(output)
```

**Output**:

```
###       ######### #########
###       ######### #########
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
###       ###       ###
######### ######### #########
######### ######### #########
```

*Feel free to ask anything regarding code.*

Comment: @rica324342 why have you chosen another answer as best?)

Comment: My teachers have a site with tests and put both codes in the site. The first one passed 8/10 tests, yours passed 2/10 tests.
Thanks for your resolution man!